# Cant upload large files - settings issue

Tags: php, apache, centos7, plesk

PHP settings set as follows:

```
memory_limit 2024M
max_execution_time 12000
max_input_time 12000
post_max_size 2024M
upload_max_filesize 2024M
```

Apache Settings

```
LimitRequestBody 0
```

I am running Plesk 12 on Centos 7

After about a minute of wait time i see 404 page with ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

I had a look at the /var/log/messages and some other logs and couldn't see anything.

What other settings could be their messing this up?

Comment: Did you restart your Apache server?

Comment: Yes I did. Didnt help

Comment: How are you uploading? Have you tried files slighly smaller than 2Gb? Are you being logged out of your app after the error?

Comment: I am not logged out; small files around 10-20 mb work fine. problem is with file sized at 600MB. I am using basic html form file upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was win Nginx, which is what Plesk is using; I had to adjust max body size from 256MB to another number.